HuggingFace transformers doesn't recognize installation of Accelerate package?
Starting HF's text generation LLM tutorial:
[https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/en/llm_tutorial]
model creation consistently hangs up. Code paste from tutorial:
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1", device_map="auto", load_in_4bit=True)

error msg:
ImportError: Using `bitsandbytes` 8-bit quantization requires Accelerate: `pip install accelerate` and the latest version of bitsandbytes: `pip install -i https://pypi.org/simple/ bitsandbytes`.

I exited Jupyter Lab, reinstalled both packages via pip, then restarted. No change.
Did I miss something?
